# Make Full Disks read-only in swift object storage

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage

I've some disks on my swift object storage that they filled and I made them read only by /etc/fstab

I think this isn't true adjustment,
Anyway, can I solve this problem (I mean full disks ) without changing the ring and just by configuring the proxy to send put /get requests to empty disks but just Get requests to full disks?

Best regards.

Comment: Making the disks read-only is unlikely to solve anything. They are full already, and you will probably get the same errors either way. According to this old thread: [this old thread][1]


  [1]: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/23461/how-to-recover-from-a-disc-full-error/, you need to add storage to the cluster, then wait until it is rebalanced automatically. If that doesn't work, perhaps deleting an object from a full disk helps (although this approach is discouraged in the above thread).

Comment: I don't see how you can tell the proxy which disks to use and not to use. Other idea: Pretend that the drives failed and replace them with larger drives. Also see https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/admin_guide.html#preventing-disk-full-scenarios for an explanation why full disks are totally unusable, and for preventing this problem in the future.